# How to convert xml empty-element tags with an attribute length into start-tag and end-tag using C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I want to convert xml empty-element tags with an attribute length

```
<tag length=”3”/>xxxxxxx
```

into start tag and end tag

```
<tag>xxx</tag>xxxx
```

using C# or XSLT

Have you got an idea ?

From :

```
    <comment>
      <opinion id="tag_1" length="93"/>
      Un bon traiteur Findi Traiteur propose un choix de 
      <topicInstance id="tag_2" length="13"/>
      pâtes cuites à la minute et d'
      <topicInstance id="tag_3" length="9"/>
      antipasti.
    </comment>
```

To :

```
    <comment>
      <opinion id="tag_1">
      Un bon traiteur Findi Traiteur propose un choix de 
      <topicInstance id="tag_2">
      pâtes cuites</topicInstance> à la minute et d'
      <topicInstance id="tag_3">
      antipasti</topicInstance>.
      </opinion>
    </comment>
```

Comment: Please give an example of showing the XML before and after you modify it.

Comment: From *what* to *what*? Can you give a real example. (Not xxxx's)

Comment: Would you be willing to consider using XSLT?  You can apply an XSLT script to an XML document in C# using the `XslCompiledTransform` class.  I suspect XSLT would be the most elegant solution, but if you're not interested, I won't waste my time on it.

Comment: I wanted to use XSLT but I had the same problem : I don't know how to retrieve the offset of start and end.

Comment: Why in the world would anyone want to do this...?

Comment: What you have written above, the to part. That is not valid xml. Is it suppose to spit out valid xml?

Comment: In order to format differently data and to use xslt and css to highlight parts of the document.

Comment: of course it is suppose to spit out valid xml, it's just a typing error. sorry for this.

Comment: @SpikeX Sometimes you just want to fix a problem with a little patch because you cannot just blow up everything and restart from scratch.

Comment: Sophie Muller: The requirements are not clear: What should be generated if the total string-length of the text of the following siblings of `opinion` is less thatn 93? What should be generated if the total string-length is greater than 93? In the absense of definitions for these requirements, I would rather not start any big effort based just on guessing. –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is a complete and simple transformation that implements the wanted processing**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[@length]">
  <xsl:variable name="vFollowingText" select=
  "normalize-space(following-sibling::text()[1])"/>

  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='length')]"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="substring($vFollowingText, 1, @length)"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
  <xsl:value-of select="substring($vFollowingText, @length+1)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()[preceding-sibling::*[1][@length]]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<comment>
    <opinion id="tag_1" length="93"/>
    Un bon traiteur Findi Traiteur propose un choix de        
    <topicInstance id="tag_2" length="13"/>
    pâtes cuites à la minute et d'       
    <topicInstance id="tag_3" length="9"/>
    antipasti.     
</comment>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<comment>
  <opinion id="tag_1">Un bon traiteur Findi Traiteur propose un choix de</opinion><topicInstance id="tag_2">pâtes cuites </topicInstance>à la minute et d'<topicInstance id="tag_3">antipasti</topicInstance>.</comment>
```

**UPDATE**:

Following the comments of @enguerran that `<opinion>` should enclose the rest of the content, here is a transformation that does that:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[@length]" mode="following">
  <xsl:variable name="vFollowingText" select=
  "normalize-space(following-sibling::text()[1])"/>

  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='length')]"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="substring($vFollowingText, 1, @length)"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
  <xsl:value-of select="substring($vFollowingText, @length+1)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[@length and not(preceding-sibling::*/@length)]">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='length')]"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates mode="following" select=
    "following-sibling::text()[1] |following-sibling::*" />
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="*[preceding-sibling::*[1][@length]] | text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document (above), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<comment>
<opinion id="tag_1">
      Un bon traiteur Findi Traiteur propose un choix de
      <topicInstance id="tag_2">pâtes cuites </topicInstance>à la minute et d'<topicInstance id="tag_3">antipasti</topicInstance>.</opinion>
</comment>
```

Comment: The wanted correct result may have the "opinion" node to be the parent of the two "topicInstance" node as its length is 93.

Comment: @enguerran: Oh. I see ... . This requirement hasn't been explicitly stated, so until your remark I hadn't noticed that `opinion` must become the parent of the two `topicInstance` elements. Thanks for alerting me to that fact. I will have a look when I find time and will implement this final requirement.

Comment: @enguerran: The requirement is not clear: What should be generated if the total string-length of the text of the following siblings is *less* thatn 93? What should be generated if the total string-length is *greater* than 93? In the absense of definitions for these requirements, I would rather not start any big effort based just on guessing.

Comment: Once upon a time some people decide not to close xml tags but add an extra attribute with length to specify the range of the xml tag. We must assert that the closing tag must be at offset 93. If there is not enough characters, it would throw an exception/error. Of course if the total string-length is greater than 93, the closing tag must be added in the middle of the string. But we must assume lengths are correct.

Comment: @enguerran: If "we must assume lengths are correct" then this is trivial to generate.

Comment: @enguerran: I have update the answer to produce the wanted output.

Answer (score 0):

This might fulfill your requirements to some degree:

```
<xsl:template match="comment/opinion|comment/topicInstance">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- copy attributes except for "length" -->
        <xsl:for-each select="@*[local-name() != 'length']">
            <xsl:copy/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!-- include characters from the following text node -->
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(following-sibling::text()[1], 1, @length)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="comment/text()">
    <xsl:variable name="previous" select="preceding-sibling::node()[1]"/>
    <!-- strip characters that have been inserted in the previous node -->
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(*, $previous/@length + 1)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

It won't cover all cases, you will need to add some checks (e.g. check whether the previous node exists etc).